# Calling a java web service (Document Type) and return complains about duplicate ID

Tags: java, web-services, duplicate-data

We have a Java web service that we call from our application.

When we call it from our app we get a Duplicate ID error. From Soap UI there is no error.

At first we thought that SOAP UI was not validating the response. We validated the response with the XSD's using XMLSpy and it is happy with the response.

Is there any way that some applications may consider ID as a reserved word? or handle it in a different way? if So what words could possible give the same issue in a XML document return from a web service?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calling application was Magic 9. Seems Magic sometimes don't like the use of a tag with the name 'ID'.

rename it to myCarId or anything else. Not ideal but this seems to be the only way we could get pass it.